# I would like to fill the breaks in a ggplot2 with colour

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, colors

I have data for several pixels of the pacific ocean (each pixel is a 250km^2 square of the ocean represented by a lat and lon value). I have the following code in R to draw my map with the minor breaks representing each pixel I have data for:

```
mp1 <- fortify(map(fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE))
mp2 <- mp1
mp2$long <- mp2$long + 360
mp2$group <- mp2$group + max(mp2$group) + 1
mp <- rbind(mp1, mp2)
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) + 
  geom_path()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Longitude",minor_breaks=seq(170,246,2), limits = c(170, 246)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name= "Latitude",minor_breaks=seq(30,64,2),limits = c(30, 64))
```

which gives:

[image]

For each pixel that isn't landlocked I'd initially like to colour in, say blue, to represent ocean. I'd also like a legend explaining this. Eventually, once I have processed the data, I would like to colour it by the classification it will be given. Will this be possible? If it helps I have a matrix of all possible lon/lat combinations that I have pixels for so they would be available for referencing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = group)`

Answer (score 0):

`mp2` looks like its derived from a shapefile or vector data; I'm assuming you have a second raster (pixel) data layer. You could try using `geom_raster` or `geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) +
  geom_raster(data = rasterdat, aes(fill = colorvar)) +
  geom_path()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Longitude",minor_breaks=seq(170,246,2), 
    limits = c(170, 246)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name= "Latitude",minor_breaks=seq(30,64,2),
    limits = c(30, 64))
```

where `rasterdat` is your dataframe of raster data and `colorvar` is some field that is used to specify the color. I'm also assuming that you can reshape your raster data so it has `lat` and `lon` columns like `mp2`. Note that you should add the `geom_raster` aesthetic BEFORE `geom_path`, so that the map lines are drawn on top.